# Is polymeric ethylene glycol conductive?

Tags: organic-chemistry, electricity

The other day, when we were doing the chapter *Polymer Chemistry* my teacher mentioned that Polymeric Ethylene Glycol (PEG) is *conductive*.

[EDIT- By 'conductive', I guess my teacher meant, "sufficiently conductive, so that it can permit a significant amount of current"...Now I *really* don't want to go and elaborate on "significant"]

Naturally I was taken aback, having lived all my life believing anything even *remotely* related to plastics could possibly conduct electricity. So I Googled it, but *that* endeavor wasn't particularly fruitful. I ended up getting links to articles like these: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S001346861101190X

As I wasn't able to get my hands on any piece of scientific literature, that definitively puts my question to rest, I resolved to have a look at the chemical structure of PEG:

[image]

But I wasn't able to identify anything that could possibly impart conductor-like properties to PEG. No free ions or any delocalized electrons that could facilitate conduction. Nothing ._.

However, I *was* able to discern something about possibly 'altering' PEG, via a method that's akin to *doping*. At any rate, I'm getting no where here.

Would anyone happen to know if PEG *really* is conductive in the pure state? Or is it somehow 'modified' to impart conductive properties to it? If so, then *how* is it modified?

A good reference would be appreciated.

Comment: Depends on what someone means as conductive.

Comment: Roger that! I'll edit it.

Comment: Uptake of water from the air might be one factor. See if you can get a hand on this article: http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/proceeding/aipcp/10.1063/1.2733226

Comment: Good link Herr @Klaus! But it mentions that the water serves to *increase* the conduction. Would you happen to know any link that covers that?

Comment: @AaronAbraham Unfortunately not. I was just curious and ran a cursory search myself ;)

Comment: @KlausWarzecha The other link was quite interesting at any rate. So *danke*! ^_^

Comment: Though not exactly common, there are still many conductive polymers. Some are only conductive when adulterated (e.g. iodine-doped polyacetylene, which led to a Nobel prize in chemistry),  but others are conductive even when pure. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductive_polymer